# What to do about old MacBook

Tags: hardware-failure, macbook, lcd

I have a White MacBook version 10.5.8. I accidentally dropped it and about an inch of the most right side of the screen is blacked out. I can't see the clock and Trash Can because of this. I checked how much it would cost to repair, and the cost of repairing is a flat rate of $300. I thought that was kind of expensive, like a third of the cost of the MacBook itself. accidentally dropping a notebook is something that would happen sooner or later, so I think getting a Lenovo is the best. I ended up getting a  MacBook pro 15 inch, but do you think it's worth the money to fix my old MacBook? I even saw some used MacBooks available on Ebay for about $400. Anyways I don't know what to do with it. I do like its screen and keyboard better than the MacBook Pro ones, because the screen is less glare-y and the keyboard is more crisp and fun to type on, and its more wieldy when I'm using it while lying down.

Comment: Buy a new screen from ebay or somewhere and repair it yourself. Laptops aren't that difficult to disassemble/reassemble. Otherwise, if you don't want to do that, send it to me. I could use a MacBook... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how old your MacBook is, but a laptop older than 3 years is usually not worth repairing.  You can still make use of it though.  You can always share the screen remotely.  You can make it into a file server, print server, web server, or something.